# Getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' when attempting to get a piece of data from MediaWiki API

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I'm attempting to code something to get various attributes from the MediaWiki API. However, it throws an error when I attempt to get certain data from the page, for example, the title.

```cs
        const reqDesc = (requestid) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: `https://example.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/AsSimpleJson?id=${requestid}`
            }, (error, response, body) => {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    return resolve(`<${body.sections[0].content[0].text}>`);
                } else if (error) {
                    return reject(`Error: ${error}`);
                } else {
                    return reject(`Response code: ${response.statusCode}`);
                }
            });
        });
```

(I know request is deprecated, I'm attempting to find something better.)

The above code should work, however at `` return resolve(`<${body.items[0].id}>`); ``, it throws 
'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: Presumably you are getting an error object back.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `request`, you could use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).
As for `'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'`, it means either `sections` or `content` is undefined. You might want to take a look at what is inside `body`.

Example:

```js
let requestid = 1;
let url = `https://example.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/AsSimpleJson?id=${requestid}`;
axios({
  url: url,
  responseType: 'json',
})
.then(response => {
  console.log('--response--');
  let section = reponse.data.sections[0] || {};
  let content = section.content || {};
  let elem = content[0] || {};
  let text = content.text;
  return text;
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(error => {
  console.log('--error--');
  console.log(error);
});
```